# Splitting date and time then transfer them to their new respective columns

Tags: php, sql

I have a website which have a date and time combined in the start of meeting and end of meeting.

Meeting_start
2019-04-26 11:39:15

I already created new columns for date and time. How can I split the existing date and time then transfer them to their new respective columns?

Ps. I'm looking for SQL codes.

Comment: Best answer: _Don't_ do this.  Keep your timestamp precisely as it is.  If you need to _view_ your data this way, then use the suggestion given by @RamRaider.

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong. I was asked to seperate the date and time in the reports so I created new columns date and time then planning to extract all records then put them to the new columns.

Comment: Read the comments below, and just use a _view_ if you want to see the time and date separately.  It is generally bad practice to store date and time in separate columns (for so many reasons).

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the date and time functions available in mySQL

```
set @d='2019-04-26 11:39:15';
select date(@d),time(@d);
```

Will output

```
+------------+----------+
| date(@d)   | time(@d) |
+------------+----------+
| 2019-04-26 | 11:39:15 |
+------------+----------+
```

Assuming that the existing column is called `meeting_start` and a table called `TABLE` you could then do

```
update `TABLE` set `date_col`=date( `meeting_start` ), `time_col`=time( `meeting_start` );
```

---

A simple table schema to illustrate how to update the new fields

```
mysql> describe `so_datetime_fudge`;
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field              | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                 | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name               | varchar(50)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| meeting_start      | datetime         | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| meeting_start_date | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| meeting_start_time | time             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+--------------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

A snapshot of the table with 3 rows of dummy data

```
mysql> select * from so_datetime_fudge;
+----+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| id | name                  | meeting_start       | meeting_start_date | meeting_start_time |
+----+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | The First of Too Many | 2019-05-27 16:48:30 | NULL               | NULL               |
|  2 | Holy Cow Batman       | 2019-05-27 16:54:56 | NULL               | NULL               |
|  3 | The End is Nigh       | 2019-05-27 16:55:22 | NULL               | NULL               |
+----+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Then running this query:

```
update `so_datetime_fudge` set `meeting_start_date`=date( `meeting_start` ), `meeting_start_time`=time( `meeting_start` );
```

Running the same SELECT query after the update

```
mysql> select * from so_datetime_fudge;
+----+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| id | name                  | meeting_start       | meeting_start_date | meeting_start_time |
+----+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | The First of Too Many | 2019-05-27 16:48:30 | 2019-05-27         | 16:48:30           |
|  2 | Holy Cow Batman       | 2019-05-27 16:54:56 | 2019-05-27         | 16:54:56           |
|  3 | The End is Nigh       | 2019-05-27 16:55:22 | 2019-05-27         | 16:55:22           |
+----+-----------------------+---------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

But, if you create a VIEW of the table you can structure this how you like and the underlying data remains unchanged

```
CREATE VIEW `vw_datetime_fudge` AS select 
    `id`, 
    `name`, 
    date( `meeting_start` ) as `meeting_start_date`, 
    time( `meeting_start` ) as `meeting_start_time` 
from `so_datetime_fudge`;


mysql> select * from `vw_datetime_fudge`;
+----+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
| id | name                  | meeting_start_date | meeting_start_time |
+----+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
|  1 | The First of Too Many | 2019-05-27         | 16:48:30           |
|  2 | Holy Cow Batman       | 2019-05-27         | 16:54:56           |
|  3 | The End is Nigh       | 2019-05-27         | 16:55:22           |
+----+-----------------------+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! But I actually have many existing datetime already saved. Is there a way to do this in one go?

Comment: Yes, update the question to include table schema - without knowing column names ( other than `meeting_start` ) hard to say... but, like @Tim Biegeleisen said - why do that... you can always use a view of the data to show the constiituent parts whenever required

Comment: The SQL code did not work. It says to check manual that corresponds with your mySQL server version.. i'm using btw version 5.5.62 Ubuntu

Comment: Hi @RamRaider I tried it again but only th date column got updated

Comment: well if you don't wish to add the table schema then it's anyone's guess. What query are you now trying??

Comment: The new column date has now the dates of the existing meeting_start dates. It now shows as 2019-04-26 00:00:00.  Is it possible to only have the date to show on the date column?

Comment: please add your sql query and table schema

Comment: I used your code a while ago. Date column is now showing 2019-04-26 00:0000 while the Time column is showing 00:00:00

Comment: I have requested several times for schema and query. If you are not prepared to help yourself then I sure am not! FYI: both `date` and `time` have special meaning in sql so to use as column names requires that these fields are encapsulated in backticks. If you decide to add the required info I'll take a look, otherwise - goodluck

Comment: Please tell me which is the schema and query. Apologies. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

$subject = 'Meeting_start 2019-04-26 11:39:15';

$pattern = '/(\d\d\d\d\-\d\d\-\d\d).*(\d\d\:\d\d\:\d\d)/U';


preg_match_all($pattern,$subject,$matches);

$date = $matches[1][0];
$time = $matches[2][0];

echo $date . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
echo $time . '<br>' . PHP_EOL;
```

gives result

```
2019-04-26<br>
11:39:15<br>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `DateTime::format` method

```
$date = new DateTime('2019-04-26 11:39:15');
$timeString = $date->format('H:i:s');
$dateString = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```